# openstreetmaps migration from apache to litespeed webserver

Tags: openstreetmap, litespeed

in my 000-default.conf of my apache configuration I have the following directives in order to make my Open Street Map tileserver work.

```
LoadTileConfigFile /usr/local/etc/renderd.conf
ModTileRenderdSocketName /var/run/renderd/renderd.sock
# Timeout before giving up for a tile to be rendered
ModTileRequestTimeout 0
# Timeout before giving up for a tile to be rendered that is otherwise missing
ModTileMissingRequestTimeout 30
```

Now I'm trying to migrate to litespeed(I'm a total newbie at litespeed) but don't know where to configure these renderd/modtile settings in litespeed.
Anyone knows where I should put these?

I assume that this should be in my vhconf.xml file but what exactly should I modify?
(I'm running Ubuntu)
anyone any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, Open Street Map tileserver is written as an Apache module, it wont be compatible with LiteSpeed. You may need to keep Apache tile server running on a different port, let litespeed proxy requests for the map image to Apache.